# How to embed or integrated a custom WordPress Widget into the theme?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, widgets

I have my custom theme, and I would love to embed/integrate widget into it so that it show up in **Available Widgets** when I activate my theme. I did a lot of research, but I didn't find a great answer.

Here is what I meant. My custom widget should show up here immediately after the theme is activated:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? A quick Google search for "create custom WordPress widget" nets many tutorials - if you can share the code you've tried and what's not working we're more likely to be able to help.

Comment: @WebElaine I wasn't trying to create a widget, but embed a working widget into the theme. I already have a solution for it, and I wrote the answer as this might help anyone in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research, I finally get it to work the way I wanted. I would give a full credit to **Catch Box** WordPress theme because I studied and used their codes.

**Quick Note:**

- There are only two files you need to touch. `function.php` and `inc/widgets.php` from **Catch Box** theme.

**Solution:**

1. Step One:

   - In your theme's root directory, go to function.php.
   - Open it. At the end of the file, add this following line of code:

`require trailingslashit( get_template_directory() ) . 'include/widgets.php';`

2. Step Two:

   - Assuming your theme has a folder called *include* just like mine. Feel free to have any name you want. Go to that *include* folder and create a empty file called `widgets.php` [image]
   - Now open that empty file and paste the following code and save it. Make sure to replace the catchbox_adwidget with your own widget class. These code are from **Catch Box** theme, `inc/widgets.php`

widgets.php:

```
   <?php
/**
 * Makes a custom Widget for Displaying Ads
 *
 * Learn more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API#Developing_Widgets
 *
 * @package Catch Themes
 * @subpackage Catch Box
 * @since Catch Box 1.0
 */

if ( ! function_exists( 'catchbox_widgets_init' ) ):
/**
 * Register our sidebars and widgetized areas.
 *
 * @since Catch Box 1.0
 */
function catchbox_widgets_init() {

    register_widget( 'catchbox_adwidget' );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'catch-box' ),
        'id' => 'sidebar-1',
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => "</section>",
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ) );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Footer Area One', 'catch-box' ),
        'id' => 'sidebar-2',
        'description' => __( 'An optional widget area for your site footer', 'catch-box' ),
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => "</aside>",
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Footer Area Two', 'catch-box' ),
        'id' => 'sidebar-3',
        'description' => __( 'An optional widget area for your site footer', 'catch-box' ),
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => "</aside>",
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Footer Area Three', 'catch-box' ),
        'id' => 'sidebar-4',
        'description' => __( 'An optional widget area for your site footer', 'catch-box' ),
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => "</aside>",
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );
}
endif; // catchbox_widgets_init
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'catchbox_widgets_init' );


class catchbox_adwidget extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Register widget with WordPress.
     */
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'widget_catchbox_adwidget', // Base ID
            __( 'CT: Adspace Widget', 'catch-box' ), // Name
            array( 'description' => __( 'Use this widget to add any type of Ad as a widget. ', 'catch-box' ) ) // Args
        );
    }


    /**
     * Creates the form for the widget in the back-end which includes the Title , adcode, image, alt
     * $instance Current settings
     */
    function form($instance) {
        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 'title' => '', 'adcode' => '', 'image' => '', 'href' => '', 'alt' => '' ) );
        $title = esc_attr( $instance[ 'title' ] );
        $adcode = esc_textarea( $instance[ 'adcode' ] );
        $image = esc_url( $instance[ 'image' ] );
        $href = esc_url( $instance[ 'href' ] );
        $alt = esc_attr( $instance[ 'alt' ] );
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title (optional):','catch-box'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" />
        </p>
        <?php if ( current_user_can( 'unfiltered_html' ) ) : // Only show it to users who can edit it ?>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('adcode'); ?>"><?php _e('Ad Code:','catch-box'); ?></label>
                <textarea name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('adcode'); ?>" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('adcode'); ?>"><?php echo $adcode; ?></textarea>
            </p>
            <p><strong>or</strong></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('image'); ?>"><?php _e('Image Url:','catch-box'); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('image'); ?>" value="<?php echo $image; ?>" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('image'); ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('href'); ?>"><?php _e('Link URL:','catch-box'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('href'); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_url( $href ); ?>" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('href'); ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('alt'); ?>"><?php _e('Alt text:','catch-box'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('alt'); ?>" value="<?php echo $alt; ?>" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('alt'); ?>" />
        </p>
        <?php
    }

    /**
     * update the particular instant
     *
     * This function should check that $new_instance is set correctly.
     * The newly calculated value of $instance should be returned.
     * If "false" is returned, the instance won't be saved/updated.
     *
     * $new_instance New settings for this instance as input by the user via form()
     * $old_instance Old settings for this instance
     * Settings to save or bool false to cancel saving
     */
    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
        $instance['adcode'] = wp_kses_stripslashes($new_instance['adcode']);
        $instance['image'] = esc_url_raw($new_instance['image']);
        $instance['href'] = esc_url_raw($new_instance['href']);
        $instance['alt'] = sanitize_text_field($new_instance['alt']);

        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * Displays the Widget in the front-end.
     *
     * $args Display arguments including before_title, after_title, before_widget, and after_widget.
     * $instance The settings for the particular instance of the widget
     */
    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );
        extract( $instance );
        $title = !empty( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance[ 'title' ] : '';
        $adcode = !empty( $instance['adcode'] ) ? $instance[ 'adcode' ] : '';
        $image = !empty( $instance['image'] ) ? $instance[ 'image' ] : '';
        $href = !empty( $instance['href'] ) ? $instance[ 'href' ] : '';
        $alt = !empty( $instance['alt'] ) ? $instance[ 'alt' ] : '';


        echo $before_widget;
        if ( '' != $title ) {
            echo $before_title . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $title, $instance, $this->id_base ) . $after_title;
        } else {
            echo '<span class="paddingtop"></span>';
        }

        if ( '' != $adcode ) {
            echo $adcode;
        } else {
            ?><a href="<?php echo $href; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>" /></a><?php
        }
        echo $after_widget;
    }

}
```

I hope this helps anyone out there trying to do the same thing as me.